# iOS Development: How can I build a complex structured iPad Application?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a scenario with 3 sub-applications embedded into a main one.
I'm trying to use the splitviewcontroller to change my detailview's content, but I couldn't replace the detailviewcontroller without losing the popover.

Questions:
1-How can I build a organized structure to maintain my project?
2-How can I replace my detailviews viewcontroller by another?
3-Should I use storyboard or separated XIB's?
4-Can I "call" a splitviewcontroller from a simple view? (Login(single)->AppSelection(single)->App1(splitview).

Here is a sketch of my project
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've already got it mostly storyboarded, so I would definitely recommend that approach!

I wasn't able to figure out how to segue to a split view using just storyboards and nothing else. You will have to get the button press and replace the window's rootViewController with your split view (which you could load from a storyboard, or just a plain nib, if you wanted.)

Comment: I'll try this approach and then get back here to post a feedback. Tanks for you answer.

Comment: Yeah! You were right. After replace the rootviewcontroller all work's like a charm. I'm using a multistoryboard environment to properly divide my project... Are there a better way to do it?

Comment: Not really. If multiple storyboards work for you then there's no reaso not to do that.

Comment: Ok! Thanks for confirmation! :)