# MainApp not opening SubApps

Tags: ios, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I am doing the same kind of app as in this question:

[iOS Development: How can I build a complex structured iPad Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726007/ios-development-how-can-i-build-a-complex-structured-ipad-application)

but when I move from MainView to App1 (ViewController) or App2 (Navigation Conrtoller) I have problems.

App1 is a "web browser" and starts with a black screen.
App2 is a TableView that opens multiple DetailViews, but starts with TableView and nothing else happens.

What do I need to do to my "secondary" Apps startup as they were running alone?

** When I startup from each "secondary" App as root, they are working fine.

I call my secondary Apps with:

```
- (void)AwesomeMenu:(AwesomeMenu *)menu didSelectIndex:(NSInteger)idx
{
    if (idx == 5)
    {
        InitViewController *first = [[InitViewController alloc] init];
        first.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        [self presentViewController:first animated:YES completion:nil];   
    }
```

I am using Storyboard... should I use "segue"?

Comment: Yes, use a segue and make your life easier. In the prepareForSegue method you can pass anything you'd like to the second viewController.

Comment: But I dont like to pass anything, only go from Main App (MENU ONLY) to others SubApps (complete Apps). Segue also works for this? Any idea how to use it in my IF structure? Thanx!

Comment: Yes it works for that and is designed for that. Drag a segue from the object to your other view, set the transition type and it's that simple. If you aren't passing anything you don't even have to set the segue identifier.

Comment: And if I cant use "drag"? My main menu is Awesonmenu, and it's a dynamic menu. This is my BIG problem. Thanx again!

Comment: Drag a segue from your main UIViewController. You can call that segue from your didSelectIndex like this [self presentSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourIdentifier"];